# What is the equivalent of dcmrcv -native in storescp of dcm4che3 using command line

Tags: java, dicom, dcm4che

I have the dicom images with tsuid=1.2.840.10008.1.2.4.90 - JPEG 2000 Image Compression (Lossless Only)

But i would like to cmove with tsuid=1.2.840.10008.1.2.1 - Explicit VR Little Endian using command line.

Dcm4che2 has the option **-native** in dcmrcv to  accept only transfer syntax with uncompressed pixel data.

But i can't find in dcm4che3 for cmove. I referred this url http://support.dcmtk.org/docs/storescp.html and tried this way but it didn't work.

Receiver/Listener:

```
storescp -b LOCAL-AET@localhost:11112 +xe --directory .
```

CMove:

```
movescu -b LOCAL-AET@localhost:11114 -c DEST-AET@dest_ip:104 -m StudyInstanceUID=1.2.3.4 +B --dest LOCAL-AET
```

Could anyone help here!

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible. This is, because the C-MOVE triggers a C-STORE sub operation. The association negotiation (and by this the transfer syntax selection) between the Storage SCU and Storage SCP is done separately with a separate TCP/DICOM association.

This means, the C-MOVE cannot have impact on the transfer syntax used by C-STORE *by design* of the DICOM standard. So it is not a shortcoming of the tools you are using, it is not supported by DICOM at all.